# Selenium Web driver gets blocked after getting a popup from another popup (IE driver)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

I'm facing an issue when application I'm testing is opening a second level popup (I mean, a popup that rises another popup). I'm using Selenium for Java, version 2.42.2, with IE Driver.

My code currently manages all other flows and single pop ups windows, but when a second level popup appears my webdriver object gets irresponsive and just stuck in any method that try to get invoked. When this happens, I need to manually close the popup window and then driver method continues the execution of invoked method.

Maybe it worth mentioning, if I call the second popup from the main page (not from another popup) I am able to manage it without problems, so the problem seems to be related with the number of nested windows more than a specific problem for the page.

Take a look on below code:

```
String url = "/example.jsp"
int counter = 0;
boolean windowDetected = false;

// Waiting until page with given url gets detected
// It tries 10 times before it continues
while (counter++ < 10 && !windowDetected) {         

  waitForSeconds(1); // Just invokes Thread.sleep method, 

  System.out.println("before getting handlers, iteration " + counter + " of 10");   
  Set<String> handlers = driver.getWindowHandles();
  System.out.println("after getting handlers, number of handlers: " + handlers.size());

  for (String handler : handlers) {

    try {
      System.out.println("Moving to " + handler);
      driver.switchTo().window(handler);
    }
    catch (NoSuchWindowException e) {
      System.out.println("Window not found, it probably redirected to a different window");
      break;
    }

    if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(url)) {
      windowDetected = true;
      waitForPageLoading(); // It just verify current page status to be completed
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to position properly the driver in specific window with above code in other application pages, but when having the second level popup it just hangs on line Set handlers = driver.getWindowHandles(); that is the first method called on driver object after popup appeared. Similarly, if I had called another driver method like driver.getPageSource() the same would have happened in that method.

I am not able to change application structure (my scope is only for testing it), so doing changes in web application code is not an option for me now. I have read on different options like trying Robot class, but I think it will be difficult to implement with more complex pages and difficult to maintain.

Any idea of how can I solve this issue? Many thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Alberto.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look on IEDriverServer changelog, moving to a newer version of this driver solved the issue. Previous was 2.24.2, and now using 2.44. A slightly different behavior but that accomplishes what I wanted